# Map / (root URL) in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mapping, url-routing

This is something that I think should be very easy, but so far I have not been able to get it to work.

What I want to do is map my root path to a Spring MVC Controller. With a normal `Servlet`, I would just add a mapping for "`/`" in my `web.xml`, and it would pick it up quite well. But with Spring MVC, not so much.

I have tried many combinations, but none seem to work. I think the following one should work.

In `web.xml`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In my `contextConfigLocation` file:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
    <property name="mappings">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="/" value-ref="rootController"/>
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="rootController" class="my.package.RootController">
```

Then obviously, there is the case of the controller itself. I have no clue how to map the method to the actual root path. My attempt is something like this:

```
public class RootController extends MultiActionController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView display(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        final Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("someVariable", "Hello, MVC world.");
        return new ModelAndView("rootPage", model);
    }
}
```

So let's say my application runs on `http://localhost:8080/app/`, I want that exact URL to execute the method `display`. I do not want to type anything after `/app/`. In fact, some things after `/app/` are mapped to other controllers, and that all works fine (and they have to keep working).

What am I missing here? Why is this not simply working? If I use the same `url-pattern` to map to a plain `Servlet` instance, it works fine and I reach the `doGet` method, but with Spring MVC I seem to missing some particular black magic to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of mapping to `/` you can declare a welcome page in your `web.xml` file:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcome.htm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

so your `/` path will be processed as `/welcome.htm` and then if your controller is correctly mapped to `/welcome.htm` it will process `/` as if it was a `/welcome.htm` request, without making changes to other configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend getting rid of the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping and just doing the following:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class RootController
{
  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView display(...)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

This should get the result you want.  Also, add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to your servlet context with a `<context:component-scan base-package="some.package.path.to.controller" />` to have Spring wire up that controller.

Otherwise, you can probably map the URL with the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping as so:

```
<property name="mappings">
    <value>
        /*=rootController
    </value>
<property>
```

If done this way, you can keep the bean defined for rootController.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suppose that would work, but unfortunately it is not quite as easy as that. Besides this "`RootController`", we have some other `Controllers` which are set up through this `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`. Or would you then suggest to have a separate `DispatcherServlet` just for this one `RootController`?

Comment: well then keep the url mapping, but remove the entry for "/"

Comment: So you mean, keep the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`, but without the entry for "`/`", as well as add the `<mvc:annotation-driver/>` and `<context:component-scan...`?

Comment: Yeah, I'd start trying to make the move over to annotations, makes things easier and keeps your XML cleaner.

Comment: It does seem to work for this specific `RootController`, and it works nicely with my `Resteasy` servlet, but it does break all my other `Spring` `Controllers`. I will leave this open for a while to see if I get other answers, also specifically supporting my (albeit legacy) XML configuration. Otherwise, I shall mark your answer as accepted and try to gradually move this project to an annotation-based approach.

Comment: Updated my answer to maybe help with the original configuration

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Webflow, the suggestion from Boris Treukhov to use web-file-list led to my discovering a hack that worked for weblogic. For example, if welcome is a flow.xml file, do the following: Change the url-pattern from \ to *.html in web.xml. Place a dummy(empty) file welcome.htm into the folder src\main\webapp\WEB-INF. In SimpleUrlHandlerMapping map the value /welcome.htm=flowController. Finally, complete the registry, flow-location path="welcome.xml". Refer to link: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/50547-welcome-file-list-with-spring.