# WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/PMC/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat

I got warning message as follows:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/PMC/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'
```

This is my spring bean definition:

```
<beans xmlns="springframework.org/schema/beans"; xmlns:context="springframework.org/schema/context"; xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:schemaLocation="springframework.org/schema/beans springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd springframework.org/schema/context springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.PMC.hellocontroller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >

        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>

        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: This is in the starting of this file:--

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

Answer (score 0):

Please, show me your controller code.
It seems there is no mapped controller method at root path.

Please, refer to [Map / (root URL) in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202302/map-root-url-in-spring-mvc).